# htmlspecialchars() equivalent in C

Tags: beginner, c, strings, html, escaping

I'm trying to write an equivalent of PHP's htmlspecialchars() in C. What is my implementation missing or doing wrong?

```
char www_specialchars_html(char *dest, char *dest_last, char *src) {
while (*src != 0) {
    switch(*src) {
        //If a special character is found, replace with its HTML entity.
        case '&':
            if ((dest + 5) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            *dest = '&';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'a';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'm';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'p';
            dest++;
            *dest = ';';
            dest++;
            src++;
            break;
        case '"':
            if ((dest + 6) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            *dest = '&';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'q';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'u';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'o';
            dest++;
            *dest = 't';
            dest++;
            *dest = ';';
            dest++;
            src++;
            break;
        case '\'':
            if ((dest + 6) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            *dest = '&';
            dest++;
            *dest = '#';
            dest++;
            *dest = '0';
            dest++;
            *dest = '3';
            dest++;
            *dest = '9';
            dest++;
            *dest = ';';
            dest++;
            src++;
            break;
        case '<':
            if ((dest + 4) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            *dest = '&';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'l';
            dest++;
            *dest = 't';
            dest++;
            *dest = ';';
            dest++;
            src++;
            break;
        case '>':
            if ((dest + 4) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            *dest = '&';
            dest++;
            *dest = 'g';
            dest++;
            *dest = 't';
            dest++;
            *dest = ';';
            dest++;
            src++;
            break;
        case '\\': //Not required in HTML.
            if ((dest) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            src++;
            break;
        default:
            //Default for characters that don't need to be replaced.
            if ((dest + 1) > dest_last) {
                return 1;
            }
            *dest = *src;
            src++;
            dest++;
            break;
    }
}
*dest = 0;
return 0;
}
```

The function takes pointers to the destination, the last element of the destination and the source. It returns 1 if it can't write to the destination, and returns 0 when it has successfully copied to the destination. I'm still a relatively new C programmer.

Comment: Can you explain the `case` that handles the backslash character?

Comment: @200_success I had put in the backslash case so that I could use the same function to escape SQL queries, but I'm pretty sure it's not required in HTML. I'll update the code to reflect that.

Comment: @wispi For what it's worth, PHP is implemented mostly in C. For example, [here's](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8d3f8ca12a0b00f2a74a27424790222536235502/ext/standard/html.c#L1482) the PHP declaration of `htmlspecialchars()`. You can then follow the function calls to see how they do it. If you're goal is to write an equivalent implementation, it would be a lot more work because of all that [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You shouldn't pass a `char*` as buffer end but a `size_t size` corresponding to the size of the allocated buffer. So your available `length` will be `size - 2` ("zero-indexed" and "trailing `'\0'`").
- You return either 1 or 0, why don't using `bool` as return type? (Or maybe a `size_t` corresponding to the final string length, but, that's a design decision).
- Variables where value doesn't change in your function (as locales or parameters) should be marked `const`. That's not faster but it show your intends.
- You can maybe use `strcpy`, `strncpy` or  `memcpy` to ... copy the replacements string into destination (and replace multiple incrementation by a single `add-assign`).
- For non-special chars sequences, you can maybe get them in chunk by chunk (between two special chars) with `strcspn` or `strpbrk`. (and after, copying them with same functions than former)

---

**Edit**

This is a raw try using theses functions.

I think it is safe, with no overflow, but maybe not the optimal implement.
Don't be scared about the size, there is a lot of comments :)

I outed two functions from source (`strlen`and `replace_chrstr`), 'cause I think they are reusable somewhere.

```
#include <string.h>

// Get the position of the c char in the str string.
// -> str: a null-terminated string where to lookup
// -> needle: char to find 
// Return: Position of the char `c` or 1 past the end (strlen + 1)
size_t strpos(const char* const str, const char c)
{
    char* p = strchr(str, c);
    return p ? (p - str) : strlen(str) + 1;
}

// Scan `in_str` and replace all char occurrences from `search` 
// by corresponding string from `replace`, then place the result in `out_str`.
// -> search: A null-terminated string with all char to fiend
// -> replace: An array of null-terminated strings with index based replacement from `search`
// -> out_str: a buffer to put the result, at least as big than max_size
// -> in_str: a null-terminated string where to process replacements
// Return: length of resulting string, or length+1 in case of overflow
size_t replace_chrstr(const char* const search, const char* const* const replace,
                      char *const out_str, const char* const in_str, const size_t max_size)
{
    size_t in_offset = 0;
    size_t out_offset = 0;
    size_t index;
    size_t length;
    const size_t index_max = strlen(search);
    const size_t length_max = strlen(in_str);

    while (max_size > out_offset) {
        length = strcspn(in_str + in_offset, search);
        // buffer overflow detected, here we truncate the input string
        // we add `\0` and return max_size (equivalent to strlen + 1)
        // but maybe you want another handling
        if (max_size <= out_offset + length) {
            strncpy(out_str + out_offset, in_str + in_offset, max_size-out_offset-1);
            out_str[max_size-1] = '\0';
            return max_size;
        }
        strncpy(out_str + out_offset, in_str + in_offset, length);
        in_offset += length + 1;
        out_offset += length;
        // normal end of input string
        // add a `\0`, then return out_offset (equivalent to strlen)
        if (in_str[in_offset-1] == '\0') {
            out_str[out_offset] = '\0';
            return out_offset;
        }
        index = strpos(search, in_str[in_offset-1]);
        length = strlen(replace[index]);
        // buffer overflow detected, here we truncate the replacement string
        // we add `\0` and return max_size (equivalent to strlen + 1)
        // but maybe you want another handling        
        if (max_size <= out_offset + length) {
            strncpy(out_str + out_offset, replace[index], max_size-out_offset-1);
            out_str[max_size-1] = '\0';            
            return max_size;
        }
        strcpy(out_str + out_offset, replace[index]);
        out_offset += length;
    }
    // we never reach here, normally
    return 0;
}

size_t www_specialchars_html(char* const dest, const char* const source, size_t max_size)
{
    const char search[] = "&\"'<>";
    const char * replace[] = {"&amp;","&quot;","&#039;","&lt;","&gt;"}; 
    return replace_chrstr(search, replace, dest, source, max_size);
}
```

Comment: Using `bool` would require an extra `#include <stdbool.h>`, it's not uncommon to just use `int` in C for holding boolean values.

Comment: I know, but what's the problem about including it?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to expound on the calculations for remaining space: Arbitrary pointer-arithmetic (meaning the displacement is not zero, nor start and end point into or at the end of the same array) is not allowed.

Comment: @Calak Nothing wrong with including it. Using it would be overkill unless they use lots of boolean values elsewhere I suppose. Your answer is good in my opinion.

Comment: @Deduplicator What do you mean by arbitrary pointer-arithmetic?

Comment: @wispi: I guess he means that the function could be called with `dest` and `dest_last` parameters that aren't pointing into memory acquired by the same allocation. In that case, pointer arithmetic with those two variables is undefined.

Comment: @hoffmale The more likely scenario is that `dest + 6` or the like in the range-tests is not allowed.